# Change the border bottom color of material ui textfield

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to change the color of border bottom of the material Ui Textfield and when it focused also should change the color.

Textfield
______________ (this border color)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the color in CSS `after` selector. Here is a screenshot attached which will help you.

[image]

**Simply you need to do the following:**

```
.yourInputFieldClassName:after {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    border-bottom-color: #f44336;
}
```

Let me know if that worked.

Comment: its not working.. Btw thanks alot.

Comment: @SeT can you please share your code and a screenshot of DOM HTML and CSS?

Comment: Thank you it worked...

.auditTextFieldComp div:after{
    border-bottom-color: #e9e9f0 !important;
}
.auditTextFieldComp div:before{
    border-bottom-color: #e9e9f0 !important;
}

Comment: @SeT I my answer helped you please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect element and lookup for style which is setting the border color. You would find it's probably **.mdc-text-field__input** class. Just override it.

```
input.mdc-text-field__input {
  border-bottom-color: red;
}
input.mdc-text-field__input:focus {
  border-bottom-color: yellow;
}
```